# Firestore batch - actions which requires more than 1 write

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

*TL;DR* -
There are conventions/payloads/actions out there, which requires more than 1 batch write to take place.

It occur to me that when im adding a `set` operation to a `batch`, for an object which is using firestore `serverTimstamp` feature, it costs 2 write operations rather than 1.
Could not find any documentation about that.
The problem is, that if you wrap firestore batch with a local counter in your code, to avoid reaching the 500 threshold, you might miss-calculate batch size.

In my example, I am using Golang [firestore sdk](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#hdr-Preconditions) (but I do believe this issue will be common for all other sdk's because it derives from firestore fundamental mechanism)

```
batch.Set(ctx, docRef, struct {
    LastUpdate time.Time `firestore:"lastUpdate,serverTimestamp"`
}{}, firestore.MergeAll)

--> batch.writes was increased by 2 writes rather than 1
```

My question is - are any other special firestore values/actions etc' which might also require more than 1 batch write operation to take place?
Also do anyone can suggest a workaround for that issue?

Answer (score 2):

So-called field transform operations indeed may require more than one write operation on the server, reducing the capacity of logical write operations you can perform in a batched write or transaction. If I recall correct, you only be *charged* for one write operation in such cases though.

From the answer I gave before to [what is "field transformations" in Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70764076/what-is-field-transformations-in-firestore), it seems that the [field transform operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/Write#FieldTransform) that are available are `setToServerValue` (the server timestamp you use), `increment`, `appendMissingElements`, `removeAllFromArray`, `maximum` and `minimum`. I'm not sure if the last two are exposed on any SDK yet.